# Accessing arrays defined in in JSP

Tags: jsp, el

I have arrays of objects defined in a java class, In JSP I have instantiated object of that class using

```
<jsp:usebean id="obj" class="complete path of class"/>
```

and printing them  using

```
<c:out>${obj.array.[0].membervariable}</c:out>
```

in JSP. I have imported the class using

```
<% page import="complete path of class"%>
```

but I am not able to print the value. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<c:out>${obj.array[0].membervariable}</c:out>
```

'.' is not requried